# Caluculate the index

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to caluculate that type of index.
I understand like this question.
\begin{align}
3^2 &= 9^x\\
3^2 &= 3^{2x}\\
\text{So } 2 &= 2x\\
x &= 1
\end{align}

However I can not understand such a question. How can I solve that type of question?
$$3^x = 2$$

Comment: You will need the logarithm. In your case, $x = \log_3 2$.

Comment: I agree with the other responses.  However, I also think that it is important to notice that the actual problem that you posed is **not** asking you to solve that $3^x = 2$.  Instead, it is asking you (in effect) to solve $3^2 = 3^{(2x)}.$  The idea is that even if you **ignore** the whole idea behind logarithms, your **intuition** is supposed to *suggest* that if $a$ is a **fixed** positive real #, and $x$ and $y$ are variables, then the equation $a^x = a^y$ is supposed to imply that $x = y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that by definition for $a,b>0$ with $a\neq 1$

$$\log_a b=c \iff  a^c=b$$

then

$$3^x = 2 \iff x=\log_3 2$$

or also

$$3^x = 2 \iff \log(3^x) = \log 2 \iff x\log 3 = \log 2 \iff x=\frac{\log 2}{\log 3}$$

As an alternative since

$$2=3^{\log_3 2}$$

we have

$$3^x = 2 \iff 3^x = 3^{\log_3 2} \iff x=\log_3 2$$

where we have used that exponential function is injective.